# Frame layout set height same as width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

In my layout I am using `FrameLayout` which width is set to `wrap_content`, it depends on width of `TextView` inside of it. Now I would like height of that layout to be the same as width. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ConstraintLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` your xml file can looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```